# Squid: what does TCP_MISS/504 mean?

Tags: proxy, centos, squid

I use squid to set up a proxy but the access.log shows thant the status is TCP_MISS/504

thanks

Answer (score 1):

TCP_MISS/504 just means that the document hasn't been cached yet, so Squid was grabbing it from the actual source. If you're having a problem, it's probably something else.